# Change WPF ComboBox selection to match given value using binding and MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I'm just beginning my adventure with WPF and MVVM pattern. In my project I have DataGrid, which is populated from SQL database via Entity Framework - everything works fine here. Now I'm trying to add basic functionality - add, edit and remove data from this DataGrid and underlying database table. It is to be done with new dialog window with controls for editing each field from data row. Here are the code fragments. DataGrid and buttons:

```
                   <DataGrid x:Name="RouteListDataGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding RouteList}" SelectedItem="{Binding RouteSelected}" SelectionMode="Single"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="➕" Click="OpenRouteDialogAdd"/>
                        <Button Content="" IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, ElementName=RouteListDataGrid, Mode=OneWay}" Click="OpenRouteDialog"/>
                        <Button Content="➖" IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, ElementName=RouteListDataGrid, Mode=OneWay}" Command="{Binding RouteCmdDelete}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Code behind for opening modal window in add or edit mode:

```
Private Sub OpenRouteDialog(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim routeDialog As New RouteDialog With {
        .Owner = Me,
        .DataContext = DataContext
    }
    routeDialog.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenRouteDialogAdd(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim viewModel As MainWindowViewModel = DataContext
    viewModel.RouteSelected = New Trasa
    viewModel.RouteSelected.DataZaladunku = DateTime.Today
    viewModel.RouteSelected.DataDostawy = DateTime.Today
    viewModel.RouteSelected.PojazdID = 1
    viewModel.RouteSelected.KierowcaID = 1
    Dim routeDialog As New RouteDialog With {
        .Owner = Me,
        .DataContext = DataContext
    }
    routeDialog.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

XAML for dialog window:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MrLogistic"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" x:Class="RouteDialog"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Trasa" Height="300" Width="300" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>    
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding VehicleCmdGetList}"/>
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DriverCmdGetList}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="numer"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="1234"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="załadunek"/>
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectedDate="{Binding RouteSelected.DataZaladunku}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="dostawa"/>
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" SelectedDate="{Binding RouteSelected.DataDostawy}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="pojazd"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
              ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleList}"
              SelectedValuePath="PojazdID" DisplayMemberPath="Nazwa"
              SelectedValue="{Binding RouteSelected.PojazdID}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="kierowca"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DriverList}"
              SelectedValuePath="KierowcaID" DisplayMemberPath="Nazwisko"
              SelectedValue="{Binding RouteSelected.KierowcaID}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Text="opis"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding RouteSelected.Opis}"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="6">
        <Button Content="✔" IsDefault="True" Click="Ok_Click" Command="{Binding RouteCmdPersist}"/>
        <Button Content="✖" IsCancel="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

So it should work like this: click "add" button - create new item with default values and pass it as RouteSelected, click "edit" button - pass DataGrid SelectedItem as RouteSelected. Next, in both cases, edit values with dialog window controls and save changes to database on clicking "confirm" button.

It works, but I'm getting trouble with ComboBoxes when opening dialog window with OpenRouteDialog (adding new data row with OpenRouteDialogAdd works just fine). Both ComboBoxes display correct items (based on data row values) only on first window load. On subsequent loads they both reset to value "1", and DataGrid reflect this. Example: in DataGrid I select some data row with KierowcaID=4, I click "edit" button, dialog window gets loaded and second ComboBox properly displays item with value "4". I close the window (confirming saving changes or not - result is the same). I select the same data row (KierowcaID=4), I click "edit" button, window gets loaded, but this time (and any after) second ComboBox displays item with value "1" (cell value for KierowcaID in DataGrid also changes to "1"). I have no idea why this is happening, especially, that both DatePickers and TextBox display correct values every time.

Comment: Why do you use `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`? Do you actually have multiple places where the same collection is supposed to display the same selected value? CurrentItem synchronization tends to be a cause for unexpected value changes.

Comment: `RoutedUICommand` is very poorly suited to the MVVM pattern, as it has the be handled in the code-behind.  As you can see in your code, this leads to far to much code in code-behind, when it should be in the view-model or model.

Comment: @grek40: with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to false or left unspecified both CheckBoxes show nothing selected (presumably null) on second and subsequent window loads.

Comment: **@Bradley Uffner**: I don't use RoutedUICommand but RelayCommand (implemented on ICommand). I tried to not brake MVVM pattern - view's code behind is being used only to manage dialog windows and pass DataContext to them.

Comment: With a correct `RouteSelected.PojazdID` as `SelectedValue`, the comboboxes should start with a selection. You are using `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` as a cover for a different problem.

Comment: **@grek40**: I have both ComboBoxes with `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"` now - firs dialog load show correct values selected in both ComboBoxes. Subsequent loads (closing window and opening it again via button) show nothing selected in ComboBoxes.

Comment: One thing that bothers me is, you set `Window.DataContext` both in XAML and in code behind. Which one do you expect to be the actual data context in the end? The more I think about it, I really suspect that's the root cause of your problem... try to remove the `<Window.DataContext>` from XAML please.

Comment: Just to add to grek40's comment, if you are setting the `DataContext` in XAML just so you have intelli-sense, the proper way to do that is like this `d:DataContext={d:DesignInstance MainWindowViewModel}`. the `d` xmlns items are *only* applied at design-time, they are ignored at run-time.

Comment: **@BradleyUffner**: great advice on using design-time DataContext, many thanks! Moving DataContext instantiation to code-behind, changing `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` haven't helped. I've added event handler for one of ComboBoxes `SelectionChanged` event, and it looks that it fires only once on first window load, and two times on subsequent loads. Why? Finally tired of constant failures I've tried to change `routeDialog` instance to global and show / hide window instead of closing it. It works (proper ComboBoxes `SelectedValue` every time), but I know it shouldn't be done that way?